# FTP uploads have incorrect permissions when using vsftpd

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

I recently set up an FTP site using VSFTPD on Debian, and am running into an issue with uploaded directories not being able to be accessed. Files are okay but when I try to upload a directory or change into a freshly uploaded empty directory, I get the following error:

Failed to change directory.

If I go in through the shell as and chmod the correct permissions, I can access the directory with no issues. If I go in through the shell and make a new directory, there is also no issue with it, this issue only seems to be on directories uploaded via an FTP client.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. I am running Debian 7.5 (Wheezy) and the client I am using to connect is WinSCP from a Windows 7 system. I am using a chroot jail, where the the user is jailed to their home directory (which is not writeable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think there may be two causes:

1. You log in to the FTP server as `anonymous`, but the uploaded directories are `chown`'ed to another user, and they have permissions `0600`, so they become unavailable to `ftp` (or another user set by `ftp_username`) to which anonymous users are mapped by the `vsftpd` daemon.

   Try to set the following in your `vsftpd.conf`:

   ```
   chown_uploads=YES
   chown_upload_mode=0644
   chown_username=ftp
   ```

   Note that you may want to change `ftp` to something else if you already changed `ftp_username` or `guest_username`.
2. You said that uploaded files are OK, but directories are broken. That makes me think that there is something wrong with `umask`, perhaps it is set to something like `011` or `033` that causes the `execute` bit to be disabled, and therefore you cannot list directories.

   Try to fix that by setting `umask` values to `022` in the `vsftpd.conf`:

   ```
   anon_umask=022
   local_umask=022
   ```

Comment: I solved the problem earlier today. I had accidentally set local_umask twice in vsftpd.conf, and the second instance was set to  011, which did cause my issue.